# Make the invoice search results default to 200

Tags: configuration, invoice, sales

On Sales>Invoices... The invoices default to 20 per view. We have a large store and require and would prefer if the invoices defaulted to 200 per view.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying core not recommended so extend this class constructor using magento principles. Just add one line of code to constructor. If you want to modify default grid override using template update which is commented out.

for your question just update by adding one line of code in constructor. `$this->setDefaultLimit(200);`

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Invoice_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_invoice_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        //$this->setTemplate('widget/grid2.phtml'); //not needed if no need to create more paging options
        $this->setDefaultLimit(200);
    }
```

In the layout file you can do more changes which is not required in your case. if you define new layout copy this file `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid.phtml` in appropriate path.

Comment: Thanks, however I can't find the construct in the grid.phtml

Comment: Just for confirmation, is this the file I should be editing?

Comment: you will override not edit for best code practice. I actually gave the class code from this file. app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Invoice\Grid.php